# error in output the word counts in java

Tags: java, word-count

i want to counting matching and counting words.

i have two text file , and to compare words eachother.

for example,

a text file : a b c d e.

b text file : a a a a a.

and i want to see this output.

output : a 5.

but when i wrote code, it didn't works.

please help me.

i wrote code for java adk 1.8 using eclipses, windows 8.1 64bit.

this is code following this.

```
   package test1;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class ex01 {

       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub


          FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:/Users/Hong/Desktop/승현연구/152-300/301.txt");
          FileReader key_item = new FileReader("C:/Users/Hong/Desktop/승현연구/no-yes2500.txt");

          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
          BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(key_item);

          FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Hong/Desktop/승현연구/답변빈도/a301.txt");

          List<String> key = new ArrayList<String>();
          List<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();

          String in = "";
          String s = "";
          String ss[];

          while ((in = br2.readLine()) != null) {
                key.add(in);
          }
          while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                str.add(s);
          }

          ***int cnt = 0;
          int count = 0;
          int cont = 0;
          String txt = "";

          for (int i = 0; i < key.size(); i++) {
             for (int j = 0; j < str.size(); j++) {

                System.out.println(j + " " + str.get(j));

                if (str.get(j).lastindexOf(key.get(i))) {

                  cnt++;
                  //System.out.println(key.get(i) + " " + cnt);
                 }
               if (cnt == 1){
                   //cont ++ 1;
               //System.out.printf("%d",cont);
                }
             }

              System.out.println(key.get(i) + " " + cnt);

                txt = txt + key.get(i) + " " + cnt + "\n";

                cnt = 0;

               }
           file.write(txt.getBytes());

          }***

          //System.out.println("Hello Java");


    }
```

in my coding, error causeing this line
[ if (str.get(j).lastindexOf(key.get(i)))]
i don't know why
this is summary for explain text file and what i want to do

First, the code i'd like to see is to compare 301 text file and no-yes2500 text file and output the word counts belonging to no-yes2500
(ex : apple  3
      banana 2 )

- 301.txt is a text file that consists of sentences about Q&A community answers.
- no-yes2500.txt is a keyword list

Comment: So, i think i get your program but what is your question?

Comment: aaaa my question is this.
this code causeing error for  if (str.get(j).lastindexOf(key.get(i))) this line. and, i want to fix this code. and want to know why this error appear

Comment: What is `a 5` then ? Is it total number of **a** in b text file ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna that is just example. there is noting to mean
i said that a text file contain "a" "b" "c" "d" "e".
and b text file contains "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "a". but that is just example nothing to importants

Comment: @L.kyunam OK then post your stacktrace and inform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str.get(j).toString().lastIndexOf(key.get(i).toString())>=0
```

Try this

Comment: i tried this. but error message appear...
error name is "Obsolete Methods on the Stack." 
and [reason is The virtual machine was unable  to remove all stack frames running old code from the call stack. The virtual machine is not supplying the debugger with valid data for those frames, Stepping into these obsolete frames may be hazardous to the target virtual machine.]
why this happening?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code, replace `lastindexOf` with `lastIndexOf` and make the expression in the if-clause to evaluate to a boolean, currently its an int (i.e. an index)